# Is $f(x,y)=ax^2+by^2, \ a,b \in \mathbb R $ a bijection between $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$? Bijections of topologies

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functions

Is $f(x,y)=ax^2+by^2$ a bijection between $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ ?

How about $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}+ \frac{z^2}{c^2}? ( \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R )$

> What confuses me now is this: My professor defined the function
>   $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ then stating : $f^{-1}((1,2))=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:
>  1 < f(x,y)<2\}$ Then, what I can assume the logic: since $(1,2)$ is
>    open in $\mathbb R $ then $f^{-1}((1,2)) $ is open in $\mathbb R^2.$
>   What are your thoughts on this?

And also, if a have a bijective between two topologies, are the following statements correct:

1.)If a subset in one topology is open/closed its map is  open/closed as well in the respected topology.

2.)If a subset is nor open nor closed in one topology its map is nor open nor closed in the respected topology.

3.) If a subset is open and closed in one topology then it's map is open and closed in the respected other topology.

Comment: Nota a bijection, $f(1,0)=f(-1,0)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas When you get the chance,check out my edit. :)

Comment: In the highlighted bit, what is it that confuses you? There is nothing apparently wrong with the statement about $f^{-1}((1, 2))$.

Comment: I understand now, from the viewpoint of continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=b=1$, then $f$ is not surjective, as $f(x) \geq 0$. Notice $f(x,y)=f(-x,y)=f(-x,-y)=f(x,-y)$, what can you say about injectivity of $f$? Edited :  Added after your request : Notice that $f$ is a continuous mapping, from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ ( taken with the standard Euclidean metric) to $\mathbb{R}$. Under a continuous map, the preimage of an open set is open and a closed set is closed. However, the image of an open set might be not open, (eg $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \to \sin x$ $f(]0,3\pi[)=[-1,1]$). I will leave other examples to you.

Comment: I edited my question, would appreciate if you could give input on highlighted.